# Hard Drive space used but files are in found.000 and cannot be accessed

Tags: hard-drive, virtualbox, backup, external-hard-drive, file-corruption

I had used Virtualbox for a virtual machine which had froze for a long period of time and would not close by shutting it down normally. I closed it by clicking the cross and restarted my machine. I believe it corrupted the files on the external hard drive. I used the windows scan for external devices to try to fix it and it seems to have removed a couple hundred gigs (most likely the corrupted virtual machine), I’m not too fussed about it as I have a backup on the same hard drive (dumb but I don’t have another external hard drive). I would like to retrieve this backup but the external hard drive appears to be empty but the space is used when I view the drive. I’ve done a chkdsk overnight on the external hard drive and made sure that the files aren’t hidden by showing all hidden files.

I've found that the files are in found.000, which is not accessible in the hard drive. How can I recover this data?

Thank you

Comment: John, Cant understand what is last words- sus af?

Comment: Take it as “sketchy”, so many sites are trying to offer solutions to problems with their software and there are so many of them. Afraid of installing a virus as i don’t know which softwares are reputable.

Comment: chkdsk is the worst idea in case the goal is data recovery.

Answer (score 0):

The found files are what is recovered when you run chkdsk. There are 3rd party utilities you can use to try and recover data from them. I don't have any experience using them but google shows there are 'unchk' and 'filechk' that might be helpful. Since they are essentially fragments of files, it's not a simple 1:1 operation to get data back and presumably these utilities look for specific data types or file headers and try to rebuild the files from there.